# AWS EC2 Logging In via ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having a lot of issues w/ssh and EC2.  I have 2 instances, 1 elastic IP (associated with one of the instances), and a key pair file (pem).  Both instances are stock Amazon OS (Linux flavor).

I can log into one of my instances (the one without the elastic IP associated with it) like this:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/ec2_MyKey.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-224-199-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Then I try to get into the other one:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/ec2_MyKey.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-225-98-213.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

and I get a permission denied error.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are the instances newly created, or have you used one or both of them previously? Someone being careless with `chmod` on the server could cause this issue (as I learned the hard way only today, as it happens). Failing that, at risk of being insulting, are you sure they both have the same hostkey, and that the URLs and users are correct?

Comment: Hey Mark, I think I have the same problem you did (I was careless with chmod). I had no idea it could lock me out of the server. How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear this was either a bad instance, or more likely, I screwed something up.

I created a new instance and can log into it fine.